# Why does this python code have a syntax error?

Tags: python

To practice python, I made a simple class for a tree structure in which each node can have infinite child nodes.

```
class Tree():

  def __init__(self, children, val):
    self.children = children
    self.val = val

  def add(self, child):
    self.children.append(child)

  def remove(self, index):
    child = self.children[index]
    self.children.remove(child)
    return child

  def print(self):
    self.__print__(0)

  def __print__(self, indentation):
    valstr = ''
    for i in range(0, indentation):
      valstr += ' '
    valstr += self.val
    for child in self.children:
      child.__print__(indentation + 1)
```

However, I have a syntax error in the line `def print(self):`. Where is the error? I have been looking for a long time, and it seems like the right way to define a python function.

I have also tried

```
  @override
  def print(self):
    self.__print__(0)
```

to no avail.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Python 2 `print` is a keyword, so you can't use it as the name of a function or method.

Answer (score 3):

In Python 2.7 (and maybe other versions) you can override the print statement with a print function and than override that function.

To do that you have to add

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

as the first line of your file.

Comment: In Python 3, they do not even need the `__future__` import; `print()` is always a function and can therefore always be overridden, and the exception reported by the questioner will not occur.

Comment: If you read the `help('__future__')`, you'll come to a line where it says:  "No feature line is ever to be deleted from this file.".  To me this implies that importing features which are already standard in that version of the interpreter simply does nothing (and is completely allowed).

Answer (score 2):

In Python 2 `print` is a reserved word and cannot be the name of a variable or method or function.